# Difference between ptr,*ptr and &ptr

Tags: c, pointers

I've recently been studying pointers in C, and I can´t seem to fully understand this code:

```
int *ptr= (*int) 99999;
*ptr = 10;
printf("%d\n,*ptr);  //Outputs: 10
printf("%p\n",&ptr); //Outputs: 0029FF14
printf("%p\n",ptr);  //Outputs: 0001869F
```

Questions?

1. Is "&ptr=0029FF14" the memory location where "*ptr=10" is stored?
2. Is "ptr=0001869F" the memory location where "&ptr=0029FF14" is stored? If not then what is ptr?

Thank you!

I believe this question is different from the "C pointer syntax" post because it doesn´t distinguish between ptr,*ptr and &ptr, meaning that post doesn´t explain why "ptr" contains different values depending on the operator it comes with.
[EDITED]

Comment: Why do you think choosing a random memory location will work? aka this line `*ptr = 10;`

Comment: That code does not give those outputs, and in fact does not compile.

Comment: @EdHeal This line is not the problem. `int *ptr= (*int) 99999;` is.

Comment: @glglgl - I beg to differ. The poster can set that to any value as long as the poster does not use it!

Comment: there is no `a` defined in this code

Comment: When you copy/paste your homework code, please include all the data declarations.

Comment: @lglgl & Ed Heal, "An integer may be converted to any pointer type. ..., the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation"

Comment: I am sorry @Martin James, I wrote "a" instead of "ptr" because i had it with "a" in my code. All data declarations are now in the code.

Answer (score 3):

- `ptr` is the pointer itself.
- `*ptr` is the value it points to.
- `&ptr` is the address of the pointer.

So IOW,

1. `&a` is the memory location where `a` is stored.
2. `a` is the memory location where `*a` is stored.

Answer (score 2):

Let us fix a few things:

```
int *ptr= (*int) 99999;
*ptr = 10;
```

Never do that unless you know what you are doing (you are juggling chainsaws)

Instead lets make a real int and play with it.

```
int test_int = 10;
int *ptr = &test_int;
printf("%d\n",*ptr);      //Outputs: 10
printf("%d\n",test_int);  //Outputs: 10 too
printf("%p\n",&ptr);      //Outputs: the location of ptr - its address
printf("%p\n",ptr);       //Outputs: the location of test_int
printf("%p\n",&test_int); //Outputs: the location of test_int too
```